# Calculate the amplitude and the frequency of the magnetic force acting on an electron

Tags: electromagnetism, frequency, intensity

A free electron is located in the electromagnetic field of a laser with a given wavelength and intensity.
Is it possible to calculate the amplitude and frequency of the magnetic force that is acting on the electron?